# How to ignore verify email when login socialite network in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have tried to get users to update more information before email verification but that was pointless, it was still sent to verify/email[enter image description here][1]

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
        Auth::login($authUser);
        $choose_role = 0;
        if (Auth::user()->role_id == $choose_role || Auth::user()->location_id == $choose_role) {
            return redirect()->route('update-info', Auth::user()->id);
        } else {
            return redirect($this->redirectTo);
        }
    }
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkS2v.png
```

Comment: before creating the user inside the database set the `email_verified_at` column to `now()`

Comment: I still do not understand

Comment: When you `findOrCreate` the user set the `email_verified_at` property to the current timestamp... Something like `$authUser->email_verified_at = now();` then the [verify middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/verification) won't redirect the user because it will see him / her as verified